# How to use camera to control direction while moving?

Tags: game-engine, camera, logic-bricks

I have a current setup whereby the camera can pan 360 around the character when stationary, but how can I make it so that forward movement snaps towards the direction of the camera? I.e. you can use the mouse to turn while in motion. Is there a way to achieve this via logic bricks? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add another camera. (just select the one you have and press Shift-D -> by doing this it is perfectly aligned and parented to your character and this is what you want)

Then you can use this node setup:

[image]

What it basically does is: change to camera, whenever you press w or a. Change to camera.001 whenever you press d.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=O5MD5Zg2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/O5MD5Zg2/) for some reason the movement messes up with this setup

Comment: please recheck your (old) uploaded file because i didn't change anything of your movement...

Comment: Hello. The old file has normal movement (you can check the original file), but when I add the logic node setup the movement messes up (you can check the new link). Thanks though

Comment: Are you sure, the movement messes up or are u just irritated because you are looking through 2 different cameras while pressing different keys?

Comment: Perhaps my program is the issue. I end up moving towards the sky for some reason. Thanks anyways though.